# deploy redis on okd redis.exceptions.ResponseError

Tags: python, redis, okd

I am deploying redis on okd4 with below config for service and deployment:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service


metadata:
  name: redis-service
  annotations:
    metallb.universe.tf/address-pool: vpn-access
spec:
  
  selector:
    app: redis
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379

  type: LoadBalancer
```

deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: redis:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
```

and I wanna write to Redis by Python but I am getting this error :

> redis.exceptions.ResponseError: MISCONF Redis is configured to save
> RDB snapshots, but it's currently unable to persist to disk. Commands
> that may modify the data set are disabled, because this instance is
> configured to report errors during writes if RDB snapshotting fails
> (stop-writes-on-bgsave-error option). Please check the Redis logs for
> details about the RDB error.